# Calling the Outlook COM library using xp_cmdshell from within SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, outlook

First off, forgive me if this question appears amateur or has been answered in the past - I'm pretty new to programming in general and have tried to search for an answer.

I'm trying to write an executable that will access an Outlook mailbox, pick up an unread email and insert its details into a database for our records.

I've written a proof of concept application that I can run fine but when I try and call it through a stored procedure in Sql server I hit the error message:

Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_

I imagine I'm hitting a security issue along the way but maybe, due to my inexperience, this simply isn't possible with Microsoft security settings?

So far I've tried:

-Using regsvr32 to register the .dll
-Changing the permissions of the .dll
-Setting up a Sql server proxy account that is the same login as the one I use to access the VM where the server is hosted
-Trying to run it using both late and early bound methods

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm pretty stumped!

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this from inside SQL Server?

Comment: I think because it was seen as a more elegant solution, having it self contained. Do you think there is an easier way?

Comment: Your application (and hence Outlook) in this scenario would start under the user account Sql Server is configured to run under, this account does not have permission to interact with the Office automation objects.  You could fix this via the DCOM config in Component Services - but as has been said this is a bad idea, you would be better off making your application do its thing outside of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Just because something can be done, doesn't mean it should :) Going from SQL Server to Outlook via xp_cmdshell has so many possibilities for failure that I wouldn't even contemplate it. You might get it working on one machine then find that you just can't get it working on another.

The simple way to do this would be a small .Net app; query Outlook + write to database. If you want it to work on a continual basis either use a scheduler or create a Windows service to perform the task every n minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll look into doing this outside of sql server I think!

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

I'd suggest choosing another model of calling/working with Outlook. For example, you can automate Outlook from a standalone application. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information. Also you may consider developing an Outlook add-in which can synchronize emails on the fly (when they arrives).